# Creating Locator using 2010 Census Block Group data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, census, address, geocoding

When I attempt to create an Address Locator in ArcMap using the shapefile (El Paso County, Texas) I download from the census website (t1_2010_48141_bg10.shp) I am not sure which alias names to match with the required field names.

Do I need to download a different shapefile?

Comment: Census files usually have pretty extensive metadata. I'd start there.